# I have android application that uses Google pay service for subscribing users to some packages

Tags: android, subscription, google-pay

I have android application that uses Google pay service for subscribing users to some packages.

The package is set to 20$
I need to make some internal discounts for some users as coupons for assuming 3$
How can I change the price while paying for subscription to accept 17 only not the total fixed to 20$?

Comment: If you want help, show the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.